# Noise instead of shadows around my windows

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I'm getting noise around my windows in ubuntu 16.04. I have a fairly normal installation with nvidia graphics card. I don't remember what led to the noise-shadows, but I guess it occured after some apt-get upgrade. Any suggestions. I seem to have both the nvidia-367 and nvidia-375 installed. Below is a screenshot of the problem.